# Myqsl Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

Linux updated to [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

After the update, without knowing since it was an old project done mostly in pure PHP (no frameworks) and MySQL for the DBMS usually it was on [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29). As of now, most of my LAMP projects don't work any more (giving the same error) and when I try to connect to a MySQL database like below

```php
<?php

    /*
    * Created by neno
    * website: www.mynamejeff.com
    */

    // Class DbConnect
    class DbConnect
    {
        // Variable to store database link
        private $con;

        // Class constructor
        function __construct()
        {

        }

        // This method will connect to the database
        function connect()
        {
            // Including the constants.php file to get the database constants
            include_once dirname(__FILE__) .'/Constants.php';
            // Connecting to the MySQL database
            //mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

            $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            //$connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');
            // Checking if any error occurred while connecting
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
            // Finally returning the connection link
            $this->con = $connection;
            return $this->con;
        }
    }
```

I get the this error  `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory in`.

I have searched and tried various methods such as:

- Reinstalling PHP
- Reinstalling MySQL

I even copied the `apache.conf` file to `/etc/phpmyadmin` via this rule:

```
sudo cp /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin
```

Still the error persists.

The funny thing is when I switch from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1:3306 or port 80`, I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in

When I run `sudo apache2 --help`, I get this output:

```
[Fri Apr 09 14:53:39.934038 2021] [core:warn] [pid 62907] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Apr 09 14:53:39.934100 2021] [core:warn] [pid 62907] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Fri Apr 09 14:53:39.934114 2021] [core:warn] [pid 62907] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Fri Apr 09 14:53:39.934118 2021] [core:warn] [pid 62907] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Fri Apr 09 14:53:39.934128 2021] [core:warn] [pid 62907] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Apr 09 14:53:39.940952 2021] [core:warn] [pid 62907] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Apr 09 14:53:39.941084 2021] [core:warn] [pid 62907] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Apr 09 14:53:39.941092 2021] [core:warn] [pid 62907] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

I have fixed my `php.ini` file in the `/etc/php.ini` as such *this reduced some errors*. I am not sure where.

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I have tried adding the port directly, but I still get the same error:

```php
$con = sysqli_connect("localhost:**3306**", "DB_USER", "DB_PASS", "DB_NAME");
```

I have tried to *alter* the user in my SQL like so:

```
ALTER USER 'mysqlUsername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mysqlUsernamePassword';
```

And still the error exists.

At some point I got this error too,

> : mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied

How I fixed it I am not really sure.

I have read some place that I should edit the *my.cnf* file

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

/etc/my.cnf

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf

[DATADIR]/my.cnf

~/.my.cnf
```

This file is always empty and the line I should edit is nowhere to be found.

Comment: You describe multi issues here which are independent. Please separate those things. Example: an apache lock directory has nothing to do with the database server.

Comment: I suspect your configuration relies on a socket file to connect to mysql, which your new http server actually tries to connect via network.

Comment: Why are some lines of your code commented out?

Comment: Does the socket file `/tmp/mysql.sock` exist at all? And if so, what are the permissions?

Comment: @arkascha how do I check for the permissions in the /tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: It is a node in the file system. So you can check it like any file: `ls -l /tmp/mysql.sock` ...

Comment: @arkascha I did i got this result ` ls: cannot access '/tmp/mysql.sock': No such file or directory`

Comment: OK, so that is your answer: you configured your php mysql client to use a file system based socket for the connection, but that socket does not exist! I assume you forgot to tell your mysql server to use that socket too...

Comment: You should have something like that is your mysql server configuration (probably something like `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`): `socket = /tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: Using a socket does make sense, it reduces the overhead of using a fill network connection between php process and mysql server. But for that _both_ partners need to use that socket...

Comment: where should i add this configuration.because i did add `mysqli.default_socket= /tmp/mysql.sock` in my `/opt/lampp/etc/phph.ini` but I think i might not have created the /tmp/mysql.sock. how do i create this file.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is probably divergence between versions of the MySQL. In some cases (mayor versions, for example), the file structure is different.

Comment: 2. incompatible versions of the mysql server would lead to a different error message than the one posted by the OP.

Comment: 3. the internal file structure of the mysql server is irrelevant to the outside, it is an _internal_ detail which would get handled by an update.